# How can I get my makefile to compile/link older and newer GCC/GNU libraries? C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, linker, makefile, gnu

I have GNU 4.7.1 as the default on my MacBook. I keep getting tons of segfaults when I run my program on my school's server. I downloaded the current state of my program from my schools server so that I could use NetBeans to help with debugging. I've run into tons of problems getting the newer GNU to replace the ancient 4.2 version that my MacBook was continuing to set as the default.

The OSX compilers are completely new to me and I can't get my makefile adjusted to compile everything like it is on my school's server.

People have told me to use gcc or g++ instead of the other, but others have told me that it shouldn't matter. From what I understand, OSX uses different libraries for the newer versions of GNU for c/c++ and now Clang is the standard? I'd like to stick with GNU/GCC just because that's what I've used in my CS classes.

Currently it appears that when my makefile tries to link "std::mt19937" it can't find the header that links it.

**My question is**: how can I get my makefile to compile so that std::mt19937 and the c++11 libraries both are used?

### makefile

```
OBJECTS = Ammunition.o Armor.o Consumable.o Creature.o Entity.o Gold.o Item.o parser.o Potion.o Scroll.o Weapon.o XMLSerializable.o CreatureFactory.o DungeonLevel.o Player.o Tile.o ItemFactory.o
HEADERS = Ammunition.h Armor.h Consumable.h Creature.h Entity.h Gold.h Item.h parser.h Potion.h Scroll.h Weapon.h XMLSerializable.h CreatureFactory.h DungeonLevel.h Player.h Tile.h ItemFactory.h

all: Jhack

# I tried this and adding $(LIBS) where "-std=c++0x" is below.. 
# LIBS = -std=c++0x -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11

%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    gcc -c $< -o $@ -std=c++0x

Jhack: $(OBJECTS) main.o
    gcc -o Jhack $^

clean:
        rm -f *.o Jhack

run: Jhack
    ./Jhack
```

I tried swapping out "-std=c++0x" for -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11. I also tried adding them both. I also tried swapping gcc out with g++ but everything I seem to try or change causes more errors and warnings.

Here's the first part of the current error message (It goes on and on and on):

```
gcc -c Ammunition.cpp -o Ammunition.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Armor.cpp -o Armor.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Consumable.cpp -o Consumable.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Creature.cpp -o Creature.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Entity.cpp -o Entity.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Gold.cpp -o Gold.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Item.cpp -o Item.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c parser.cpp -o parser.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Potion.cpp -o Potion.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Scroll.cpp -o Scroll.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Weapon.cpp -o Weapon.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c XMLSerializable.cpp -o XMLSerializable.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c CreatureFactory.cpp -o CreatureFactory.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c DungeonLevel.cpp -o DungeonLevel.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Player.cpp -o Player.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c Tile.cpp -o Tile.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c ItemFactory.cpp -o ItemFactory.o -std=c++0x
gcc -c main.cpp -o main.o -std=c++0x
gcc -o Jhack Ammunition.o Armor.o Consumable.o Creature.o Entity.o Gold.o Item.o parser.o         Potion.o Scroll.o Weapon.o XMLSerializable.o CreatureFactory.o DungeonLevel.o Player.o Tile.o     ItemFactory.o main.o
ld: warning: ignoring file Creature.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7f      0x45 0x4c 0x46 0x 2 0x 1 0x 1 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the      architecture being linked (x86_64): Creature.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Creature::removeMonster(DungeonLevel&)", referenced from:
      vtable for Player in Player.o
  "Creature::dumpObjectData()", referenced from:
      Player::dumpObjectData()      in Player.o
  "Creature::setElementData(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,     std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>     >)", referenced from:
      Player::setElementData(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,     std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>   >) in Player.o
  "Creature::writeDataAsFragment(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)",    referenced from:
      Player::writeDataAsFragment(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&) in     Player.o
  "Creature::move(DungeonLevel&, Creature&, std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int,   32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615u, 11ul, 4294967295u, 7ul, 2636928640u, 15ul, 4022730752u,   18ul, 1812433253u>&)", referenced from:
      vtable for Player in Player.o
  "Creature::getHP()", referenced from:
      vtable for Player in Player.o
      _main in main.o
  "Creature::setHP(int)", referenced from:
      Player::Player() in Player.o
      Player::Player() in Player.o
      vtable for Player in Player.o
  "Creature::attack(Creature*, Creature&, std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 32ul,   624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615u, 11ul, 4294967295u, 7ul, 2636928640u, 15ul, 4022730752u, 18ul,  1812433253u>&, DungeonLevel&)", referenced from:
      vtable for Player in Player.o
  "Creature::getXLoc()", referenced from:
      vtable for Player in Player.o
```

Comment: For gcc 4.7 series, its -std=c++11, not -std=c++0x. More importantly, you should be using g++, not gcc. You are compiling c++ code, not c code. You can compile c++ code with gcc, but now you need to tell gcc what language to compile via one of the --option flags. Just use g++. Regarding the "file was built for unsupported file format" problem -- How did you build gcc? That looks to me like you built it as a cross-compiler for some target other than x86_64.

Comment: Rather than downloading gcc yourself, I suggest you use fink (http://www.finkproject.org) or macports (http://www.macports.org). Let one of those tools do all the work for you.

Comment: @DavidHammen I used macports to install it. For some reason all of the paths for developer files are so weird on my MacBook. I had a hell of a time trying to get macports to even work. I changed c++0x to c++11 and I also changed gcc to g++ and I still get errors.

Comment: you are using gcc (or g++) rather than some path-specific name. What does `which gcc` evaluate to? In other words, are you using the right gcc / g++? What is your `PATH`?

Comment: @DavidHammen which gcc give me: /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: You have the wrong PATH. That should be the gcc that comes from Apple. (You should *never* touch the stuff in /`usr/bin`.) Where did you install macports? `which port` should yield something like `/opt/local/bin/port`.

Comment: @DavidHammen Crap! It was /opt/local/bin, but no port. When I set that as the new path, I got errors saying that it was missing like everything that was in /usr/bin So I copied the files from macports path and put them in /usr/bin and set the path back to that.

Comment: You have a messed up system. It looks like you didn't install macports correctly. Copying things from the macports path to `/usr/bin` is exactly what you should not have done. You should never (repeat **never**) change the contents of `/usr/bin` on a Mac. You are asking for big trouble if you do. By doing this, you might well have put yourself in the rather undesirable state of having to recreate your `/usr/bin` and related directories from your install disk / Apple download, and then rebuilding macports so that it installs in the `opt/local/bin` directory.

Comment: I ended up fixing the problems on the server so I don't need to debug my program anymore. After school's out I think I'm going to restore my MacBook fully anyways. So many unused/hidden files chains. Thanks for your help

Comment: [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) FTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I messed up the path for my compiler and MacPorts installed to the wrong location? Fresh OSX install and proper GNU undated solves it.